# All password with '$' inside (phpmyadmin) won't work [UTF-8 problem]

Tags: mysql, php, root, utf-8

i set up a dedicaced server with a tutorial.

I set in PHP :

```
mbstring.language=UTF-8 
mbstring.internal_encoding=UTF-8 
mbstring.http_input=UTF-8 
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8 
mbstring.detect_order=auto
```

But each time there is a `$` in the password (i have one for the root of mysql + other script) the password won't work.

For example, I just removed the `$` in the password for a script, and it worked.

When i connect @root on mysql via phpmyadmin : don't work
When i connect @root via PHP : works

What can i do for this problem please ?

**PS: my password works when i connect mysql via the console**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem found, only happens on firefox. I clean up all cache + cookies. Problem solved.

Weird. But solved. Thanks all ;)

Answer (score 0):

$ in PHP has a special meaning, you should escape it if used in double quotes (") strings. Or you should use single quoted (') strings:

```
"Pa$$word"
```

won't work, while

```
"Pa\$\$word"
```

and

```
'Pa$$word'
```

will work.

Comment: but i can't escape the password in the interface of PHPMYADMIN when he ask me my password. How can i fix that ?

Comment: @Tristan does it works when you connect via console? as in "mysql -u root -p" ?

Comment: yes it works, i've just tested

Comment: #1045 - Acc�s refus� pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (using password: No)  

IT's what phpmyadmin outputs. ("accès refusé : means access denied)

Comment: @Tristan seems a problem with the configuration of phpmyadmin, as it says "using password: No". Try go back to the setup page and check the authentication options.

Comment: do you mean vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf ?
What am i looking for exaclty ?

Comment: @Tristan no, you should configure phpmyadmin via its web interface. The url should be something like http://myserver/phpmyadmin/setup

Comment: @MrShunz Page not found. Plus, it worked couple of days ago and i didn't touche anything in the configuration of phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

In your php configuration, set to vice versa of magic-quotes-runtime variable.
here is more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime. Phpmyadmin will able to support for passwords contains $.  & also use recent versions of PMA.